# dataTable output within box() in R Shiny: sizing not reactive

Tags: r, user-interface, datatable, shiny

I have a dataTable within a box() in my R Shiny app.

When I change the size of the page, the size of the dataTable doesn't change to stay within its box. My plot outputs within the same box have no problem adjusting size, but the data table does.

Thoughts on fixing the data table width?

Here's some code using R's mpg data set to demonstrate my UI issue. Play around with size of window to see the sizing issue I'm referring to.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 325),
  dashboardBody( 
    fluidPage(
      box( width = 12,
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("Summary",
                      dataTableOutput("coeffTable"))
           )         
      )
    )))

server <- function(input, output){
  data<-mpg

 output$coeffTable<-renderDataTable({
    data.table(data[,1:2])
   },options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, -1), pageLength = 5))

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: how exactly are you producing this table? (ie. what is your code...)

Comment: need my ui? let me sift through it to get to a basic structure I can share.... Basically it's a dashboard body with a box in the main section, and a tabsetpanel in the box

Comment: @patrick see new code above

Comment: just a hint, but you should really work on providing a minimal example. I doubt that one requires 13 packages, all this selectinputs or custom styles for your specific problem,...makes it unnecessary hard to dig in the code,...

Comment: oh wow that was more than i bargained for. i might come back to this later when i have time

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, @BigDataScientist. I'm pretty new to stack overflow. I'll work on streamlining in the future.

Comment: simplified my example, if anyone's interested in trying it

Comment: That works with the `DT` package. Load it with `library(DT)` and use `DT::renderDataTable` and `DT::dataTableOutput`.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks, @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: Good. I convert to an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with the `DT` package. To use like this:

```
library(DT)

output$coeffTable <- DT::renderDataTable({...

DT::dataTableOutput("coeffTable")
```